# need help counting and tallying the votes

Tags: python

**output:**
Enter first name (no capitals): jack
Hello jack, do you vote yes or no? no
Enter first name (no capitals): jane
Hello jane, do you vote yes or no? yes
yes votes: 0
no votes: 0`

```
name = "random"
yes = 0
no = 0
while (name != "jane"):
  if (name == "jane"):
    name = input("Enter first name (no capitals): ")
    vote = input("Hello " + name + ", do you vote yes or no? ")
    while not (vote=="yes"or vote=="no"):
      if (vote=="yes"):
        yes +=1
        print("Thank you jane, your vote is appreciated!")
      if (vote=="no"):
        no +=1
        print("Thank you jane , your vote is appreciated!")
      else:
        name = input("Lets try again, enter your first name (no capitals): ")
        vote = input(name + " please enter yes or no... ")
  name = input("Enter first name (no capitals): ")
  vote = input("Hello " + name + ", do you vote yes or no? ")
  while not (vote=="yes"or vote=="no"):
    if (vote=="yes"):
      print("Thank you " + name + ", your vote is appreciated!")
      yes +=1
    if (vote=="no"):
      no +=1
      print("Thank you " + name + ", your vote is appreciated!")
    else:
      name = input("Lets try again, enter your first name (no capitals): ")
      vote = input(name + " please enter yes or no... ")
print("yes votes: "+ str(yes))
print("no votes: "+ str(no))
```

the total votes for yes and no keep ending up as 0 and i was also wondering how I can print out the person's name and their vote at the end.

Comment: In all three cases your `while` condition contradicts the `if` conditions below.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
yes = 0
no = 0
while True:
    name = input("Enter first name: ")
    vote = input(f"Hello {name}, do you vote yes or no? ")
    if name == 'end':
        break
    if vote == 'yes':
        print("Thank you " + name + ", your vote is appreciated!")
        yes+=1
    elif vote == 'no':
        "Thank you " + name + ", your vote is appreciated!"
        no+=1
    else:
        print('please try again.',end=' ')
print('yes:',yes)
print('no:',no)
```

is this what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is because the `while` and `if` conditions contradict.
Here's the step-by-step process.

1. Initially, `name` is equal to `"random"`.
2. `while (name != "jane")` will be `true` because both are not equal.
3. `if (name == "jane"):` will be `false`, so it will skip this `if` block.
4. Next, user will input her `name` and `vote`
5. Let's break this part into 3 conditions:
   `while not (vote == "yes" or vote "no")`

   - Condition 1: user votes `"yes"`
     `while not (true or false)` = `while not (true)` = `while false`
     It will skip this `while` block and continue looping to the top `while`
   - Condition 2: user votes `"no"`
     `while not (false or true)` = `while not (true)` = `while false`
     The same as condition 1
   - Condition 3: user votes neither `"yes"` nor `"no"`
     `while not (false or false)` = `while not (false)` = `while true`
     Even though the execution manages to get inside the `while` block, the value of `vote` is still neither `"yes"` nor `"no"`, so it will execute the `else` condition `name = input("Lets try again...)`
6. Finally, when `name` is equal to `"jane"`, we will exit the `while (name != "jane")` loop. Both `yes` and `no` will remain zero because they never had a chance to be modified

Here's the alternative, simplified solution with a few improvements

```py
name = ""
yes = 0
no = 0

while True:
    name = input("Enter first name: ")
    # Convert to lowercase
    if name.lower() == "quit":
        break

    vote = input(f"Hello {name}, do you vote yes or no?").lower()
    if vote == "yes":
        print(f"Thank you {name}, your vote is appreciated!")
        yes += 1
    elif vote == "no":
        print(f"Thank you {name}, your vote is appreciated!")
        no += 1
    else:
        print("Please try again")

print(f"yes: {yes}")
print(f"no: {no}")
```

Test

```
Enter first name: Adam
Hello Adam, do you vote yes or no?YES --> valid answer
Thank you Adam, your vote is appreciated!
Enter first name: Barbara
Hello Barbara, do you vote yes or no?nO  --> valid answer
Thank you Barbara, your vote is appreciated!
Enter first name: Caroline
Hello Caroline, do you vote yes or no?What?? --> invalid
Please try again
Enter first name: Daniel
Hello Daniel, do you vote yes or no?no  --> valid answer
Thank you Daniel, your vote is appreciated!
Enter first name: Eva
Hello Eva, do you vote yes or no?yeS  --> valid answer
Thank you Eva, your vote is appreciated!
Enter first name: quit
yes: 2
no: 2
```